# Ember test failing on importing in config/environment

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, phantomjs, ember-testing

When I run `ember test` on a project I am getting this error

---

```
    Log: |
        { type: 'error',
          text: 'Error: Could not find module `otherapp/config/environment` imported from `otherapp/tests/helpers/resolver` at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 173\n' }
...
not ok 2 PhantomJS 2.1 - Global error: Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests index.html includes "assets/tests.js". at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 15359
---
    Log: |
        { type: 'error',
          text: 'Error: Assertion Failed: The tests file was not loaded. Make sure your tests index.html includes "assets/tests.js". at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js, line 15359\n' }
...
```

I am not sure how to debug this, since this is happening in the test suite and there is no window to debug and placing `debugger;` doesn't help. Also this is someone else's project.

This is not a problem in the ember-cli or any packages as I created a new ember app and wrote some acceptance test without any such error. I am not sure how to trace or debug this error.

Comment: Please reformat the code/quote block in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and it was a strict mode bug. I was actually declaring a property on a controller with the same name twice. 
you can debug phantomjs by mounting it onto a port and then browsing there.

put this in your `testem.json`

`"phantomjs_debug_port": 9000`

and then browse to `localhost:9000` the second link with send you to the phantom dev tools!